# PropertyName must be set to a valid property name of the control named 'xxx' in ControlParameter error

Tags: c#, asp.net, controlparameter

I am trying to properly define the control parameters for `@NumOfTransactions` and I am getting an error "PropertyName must be set to a valid property name of the control named 'rptvwTransactionResearch' in Control Parameter 'NumOfTransactions'.

My aspx file

```
<table style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">      </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptvwTransactionResearch" runat="server" Height="333px" Width="100%" Visible="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
       <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\rptTransactionResearch.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" Name="TransactionResearch_ResidentResearch" />
          
            
        </DataSources>
       </LocalReport>
     </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BANKMDFConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT r.ResidentID, r.FirstName, r.LastName, rt.TransactionDate, CASE WHEN CharIndex(' From ', rt.TransactionDescription) > 0 THEN substring(rt.TransactionDescription, charindex(' From ', rt.TransactionDescription) + 6, (Len(rt.TransactionDescription) - charindex(' From ', rt.TransactionDescription) + 6)) ELSE ' ' END AS TransactionDescription,rt.Amount FROM Resident AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN ResidentTransactions AS rt ON r.FacilityID = rt.FacilityID AND r.ResidentID = rt.ResidentID WHERE (r.FacilityID = @FacilityID) AND ( @NumOfTransactions = (SELECT count(1) FROM ResidentTransactions WHERE (FacilityID = r.FacilityID) AND residentid = r.residentid)) AND (( (rt.TransactionDate = (SELECT MAX(TransactionDate) AS Expr1 FROM ResidentTransactions AS ResidentTransactions_1 WHERE (FacilityID = r.FacilityID) AND (ResidentID = r.ResidentID) AND (DepositWithdrawalCode = 'D'))) AND (rt.TransactionSeq = (SELECT MAX(TransactionSeq) AS Expr1 FROM ResidentTransactions AS ResidentTransactions_1 WHERE (FacilityID = r.FacilityID) AND (ResidentID = r.ResidentID) AND (TransactionDate = rt.TransactionDate) AND (DepositWithdrawalCode = 'D'))) ) OR Transactionseq is null) Order by ltrim(r.LastName),ltrim(r.FirstName) ">
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="FacilityID" SessionField="FacilityID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="NumOfTransactions" ControlId="rptvwTransactionResearch" Type="String" />  
      </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my aspx.cs code snippet

```
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
                {
                    var numOfDays = Int32.Parse(txtParam.Text) * -1;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FacilityID", Session["FacilityID"].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", numOfDays);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfTransactions", txtParam.Text);

                    SqlDataAdapter adpReport = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet dsReport = new TransactionResearch();
                    dsReport = new DataSet("TransactionResearch_ResidentResearch");
                    var testing3 = dsReport.Tables;
                    adpReport.Fill(dsReport, "TransactionResearch_ResidentResearch");
                    rds.Name = "TransactionResearch_ResidentResearch";
                    rds.Value = dsReport.Tables;

                    rptvwTransactionResearch.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                    rptvwTransactionResearch.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/rptTransactionResearch.rdlc";
                    rptvwTransactionResearch.LocalReport.DataSources[0].DataSourceId = "SqlDataSource1";


                    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@NumOfTransactions", DbType.String, txtParam.Text);
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT r.ResidentID, r.FirstName, r.LastName, rt.TransactionDate, CASE WHEN CharIndex(' From ', rt.TransactionDescription) > 0 THEN substring(rt.TransactionDescription, charindex(' From ', rt.TransactionDescription) + 6, (Len(rt.TransactionDescription) - charindex(' From ', rt.TransactionDescription) + 6)) ELSE ' ' END AS TransactionDescription,rt.Amount FROM Resident AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN ResidentTransactions AS rt ON r.FacilityID = rt.FacilityID AND r.ResidentID = rt.ResidentID WHERE (r.FacilityID = @FacilityID) AND ( @NumOfTransactions = (SELECT count(1) FROM ResidentTransactions WHERE (FacilityID = r.FacilityID) AND residentid = r.residentid)) AND (( (rt.TransactionDate = (SELECT MAX(TransactionDate) AS Expr1 FROM ResidentTransactions AS ResidentTransactions_1 WHERE (FacilityID = r.FacilityID) AND (ResidentID = r.ResidentID) AND (DepositWithdrawalCode = 'D'))) AND (rt.TransactionSeq = (SELECT MAX(TransactionSeq) AS Expr1 FROM ResidentTransactions AS ResidentTransactions_1 WHERE (FacilityID = r.FacilityID) AND (ResidentID = r.ResidentID) AND (TransactionDate = rt.TransactionDate) AND (DepositWithdrawalCode = 'D'))) ) OR Transactionseq is null) Order by ltrim(r.LastName),ltrim(r.FirstName)";
                   
                    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
                }
```

The problem I'm facing is when I pass the query string in to SqlDataSource1 and set `SelectParameters`, it doesn't seem to register that parameter causing and error `Must Declare Scarlar Variable '@NumOfTransactions` . I also tried setting the controlID `rptvwTransactionResearch$SqlDataSource1` and I get an error `Could not find control 'rptvwTransactionResearch$SqlDataSource1' in ControlParameter 'NumOfTransactions'.`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the @

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfTransactions", txtParam.Text);
```

Comment: My mistake. I might have left it out by accident while messing around. But I still get the same errors even after I corrected my mistake.